# Debian Wheezy : problem installing .deb package that uses update-rc.d with dependency numbers

Tags: package-management, debian, rc

I'm trying to install a .deb file, written by us, on a new Debian Wheezy system.  The .deb file was originally written for Lenny, so is fairly old.  I've tracked down one point where the installation if failing by trying to install the package with dpkg -debug=3773 : it's trying to add some services using update-rc.d:

```
update-rc.d r-initialize-config start 12 2 .
```

This gives the error:

```
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
insserv: Service r-interfaces has to be enabled to start service first-boot
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

The script contains this as the header comments (this is the LSB header?)

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: first-boot
# Required-Start: $local_fs r-interfaces
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description:
### END INIT INFO
```

and the r-interfaces script is present and seems to run correctly.

What are the requirements of programs started by the "Required-Start:" attribute?  E.g. I changed r-interfaces to "ls" and got the same problem.  r-interfaces is a transient script and does not run as a daemon, so maybe that's the problem.  What does Required-Start: need?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the LSB headers, not the `update-rc.d` call. The headers are safe to have in Lenny, they will be ignored.

Comment: What exactly are LSB headers, and how would I go about debugging the problem?

Comment: http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts